# Вывод 3d-моделей и работа с ними c++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Я занимаюсь созданием `RTS-игры`(аналогом starcraft) и я хотел бы реализовать 3д модельки, но для этого нужен реализованный хороший движок(собственно за чем я пишу).
Но чаще всего их проблема заключается в том, что они работают только под виндой, а я чаще всего пишу под `Linux` (но хочу кросплатформенности).
Друзья, посоветуйте пожалуйста что-нибудь годное!

Comment: Я поражаюсь, какие здесь все крутые программисты! Кто пишет операционную систему с нуля, а кто не зная языка программирования, пишет сходу трехмерные игры.:)

Comment: Я пишу на сях около 2 лет, решил реализовать что-нибудь интересное мне)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я же прошу готовый 3d-движок, желательно основанный на opengl с кроссплатформенной работой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Время изобретений своих велосипедов прошло, сейчас игровые движки настолько продвинутыми стали что ничего кодить самостоятельно не надо. теперь в разработке требуются творческие профессии типа дизайнеров, сценаристов и тд. Посмотрите на тот же UNREAL ENGINE. где конечно хотя и можно дорабатывать его на С++ но там уже есть технология BLUEPRINT которая вообще позволяет не прибегать к программированию. На нем сделано подавляющая част самых популярных игр. Он кроссплатформенный.

Но все же я поскажу ваш вариант ) это движок от blender , на линуксе ничего продвинутей в этой категории нет. Он тоже кроссплатформенный.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ты не пишешь код ни там и не там, я хочу в итоге опыт получить в программирование 3d-игр, а не создать 3d-игру(разные вещи).

Comment: По-этому нужен только вывод 3d-моделей и набор команд:изменить положение, перерисоваться, скрыться и т.д.

Comment: это движок от blender. он как раз и умеет и редерить и трансформировать модели. а вот на нем только пока редактор только и работает, а игр на нем я не видел. плюс на нем же можно и модели делать для своих целей.

Comment: Мне нужен сам вывод модели, друзья советовали написать вывод 3d-моделей для opengl, но это слишком долго, так что нужно что-то немного другое

Comment: друзья правы вы ищите то что и так opengl делает по умолчанию. для этого он и создан.

Comment: проще opengl ничего нет, а что бы было быстро есть полнофункциональные движки.

Comment: Окей, тогда есть уроки по выводу моделей на экран и работы с этими моделями(событие->действие)?

Comment: вот самый быстрый старт http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/

Answer (score 0):

Советую Unity3d, на данном движке можно писать на С# и JavaScript. Linux поддерживает нормально

Comment: Мне нужен только вывод 3d-моделей.
Обработку событий и их реакцию я хочу взять на себя!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?